# Why does vue-draggable select text in Edge + IE11?

Tags: vue.js, draggable

I've encountered a scenario where [vue-draggable](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable) works as expected in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Edge and IE. There, instead of dragging the list items, the browser selects the text.

Consider this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sqssmhtz/903/).

HTML:

```
<div id="main">       
    <draggable :list="list" class="dragArea">
        <a v-for="element in list">{{element.name}}</a>
    </draggable>
</div>
```

JavaScript + Vue:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#main",
  data: {
    list:[{name:"Apple"}, 
          {name:"Banana"}, 
          {name:"Cherry"} ]
  }
});
```

CSS:

```
.dragArea{
    min-height: 10px;
    background-color: greenyellow;     
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dragArea a {
    display: block;
}
```

I can't find anything about that in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution. Use `<div>` instead of `<a>`. I cannot explain why, though.

HTML:

```
<div id="main">       
    <draggable :list="list" class="dragArea">
        <div v-for="element in list">{{element.name}}</div>
    </draggable>
</div>
```

JavaScript + Vue:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#main",
  data: {
    list:[{name:"Apple"}, 
          {name:"Banana"}, 
          {name:"Cherry"} ]
  }
});
```

CSS:

```
.dragArea{
    min-height: 10px;
    background-color: greenyellow;     
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dragArea a {
    display: block;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sqssmhtz/901/).

Comment: As it turns out, this is a double-edged solution: removing the ‹a›-ness of the element breaks the draggable-ness at other places (Firefox or Safari doesn't properly create a ghost element underneath the cursor, IIRC, or something like that).

Comment: Bug still present in latest safari even with divs.